# Java EE Singleton annotations don't work

Tags: jakarta-ee, annotations, singleton

My Example:

```
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import java.util.Random;

@Startup
@Singleton
public class Singleton1 {

    Random random = new Random();

    int a = random.nextInt();
    int b = random.nextInt();
}
```

Main class:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class ThisMain {
    @Inject
    private static Singleton1 obj;



    public static void main(String[] args) {

         obj = new Singleton1();


        for (int count = 0; count < 7; count++) {
            out.println(obj.a);
            out.println(obj.b);
            obj = new Singleton1();
        }
    }
}
```

The result is:

1165198576
-845405303
276858760
-464660166
1929818899
289671820
1187666549
96727476....

I thought random variables will be the same.
What i'm doing wrong?

Please show me a working example.

Comment: Why do you think that `@Singleton` would magically prevent you from creating a new instance?? What `@Singleton` does is ensure that the same instance is _injected_ every time. I don't see any use of CDI of any other DI framework here. Annotations aren't magical, they're metadata. You need a library to actually use them...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you explain wich library i need?

Comment: You need run your code in a Java EE 6 (or better) server for the injection to work as expected

Comment: @SteveC as this obviously isn't a web app, it isn't that simple.

Comment: Thanks! I will learn more about jee )

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of issues going on here. You are using a JavaEE API `@Singleton`. If you want to use `@Singleton` you need to package your classes into a WAR, EAR, or EJB jar file and deploy it to an application server (or other JavaEE container).

When you use JavaEE APIs and inject them, the container your application is deployed to is taking care in instantiating them so you would never use `new` to create a new instance.

If you do not want to use JavaEE APIs, and you want to only use JavaSE APIs you have two choices.

You can use the CDI dependency injection framework to manage the singleton. In that case you should change `@Singleton` (which is an EJB API, which you can tell from the import for it), to `@ApplicationScoped`. If you do that you can keep the `@Inject` line and get rid of `obj = new Singleton1()` as the CDI container will see `@Inject` and obj will be non-null reference to the CDI managed instance.

The other option is to simply make an 'old school' singleton in java. For example:

```
  public class Singleton1 {
    private static Singleton1 ourInstance = new Singleton1();

    private static Singleton1 getInstance() { return ourInstance; }

    private Singleton1() {}
  }
```

Then you can get rid of `@Inject private static Singleton1 obj;` and change `obj = new Singleton1();` to `Singleton1 obj = Singleton1.getInstance();`

No matter what solution you choose you will also want to get rid of `obj = new Singleton1();` in your loop. You never want to create new instances of a singleton.